# How do I run laravel migrations directly to live database on my local machine or on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, migration, cpanel, database-migration

I was passed a laravel backend project that's already on cpanel, both the MySql database and the laravel project itself is already live on phpmyadmin.

I did some modifications on the files on my local machine such as on the models and adding new columns and I'm trying to migrate the changes on the live database. How do I go about this without messing with the live database?

- I tried using ssh but I get even more confused on the whole process.
- I tried setting my env file to the live database config but when I run migration on my local machine laravel terminal I get a series of errors.

How can I get out of this situation?

Comment: I don't think shared hosting will provide console access. Maybe you have to move the SQL file into live manually.

Comment: can you explain better please as i have no much idea what you really do mean?

Comment: 1. create a backup of LIVE DB. 2. get your local SQL changes into the `.sql` file. 3. Run on the server. Cz IDT shared hosting will provide fully functional console access.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam on cPanel you can have console access. I really don't understand why some providers will not give you access to SSH. Changing a Laravel db with an sql import is a bad idea.

Comment: @GertB. I meant ***fully functional console access*** hope you got the point. Ex AWS EC2

Comment: @AbdullaNilam If you mean root access by "fully functional", thats not needed to run migrations. Fully functional SSH access to your own account should be standard. Side note: worst case you can also run migrations from a (password protected) laravel route.

Comment: @GertB. Please what do you suggest i solve my problem if you don't mind?

Comment: @tesseract your question is not clear. Did you change your migration files? in that case you need to run `php artisan migrate`. But you said that gives errors locally? what errors?

Comment: @GertB. i want to add a couple of new columns and do some modifications to the models and controllers of my laravel project. The project is live already and hosted on cpanel, both the laravel project and the database on mysql. How do i modify, add columns and then migrate my changes in this case?